# How to prevent square image blocks before image loads html?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

Problem: especially in Outlook, before the images are loaded the email inserts a square block equal to the width of the image. For my email, I have an image that spans the width of the email, but it's height is only 325px. Instead, it previews a 650px x 650px block. Is there any way to responsively and without Javascript prevent the square block from showing prior to images being loaded?

Code:

```
<table width="650" height="325" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <img src="#" width="100%"/>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give the image the original dimensions as the `width` and `height` attributes.

To ensure the image stays responsive you can add the following styles to the image:

```
<img src="#" width="650" height="325" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" />
```

`max-width: 100%;` ensures the image does exceed the parent element's width.

`height: auto;` will scale the height automatically to the width based on the given image dimensions.

Comment: This works. Also by default you're going to want vertical-align:middle to avoid a little gap underneath on some email clients (such as Gmails)